# the name sw does not exist in the current context c#?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am very new to programming. Have only been doing it for around 2 months.

I keep getting the error "The name sw does not exist in the current context" 
i have declared "using system.IO;" at the top.

Really have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
        //enter new user

        if (iOption == 2)
        {
            //Enter new user information and add them to file
            Console.Write("Please Enter the number of users you wish to log: ");
            iUserNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //open file for writing, in APPEND mode
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("NewUser.txt", true))

                //loop for each user
                for (iCount = 1; iCount <= iUserNumber; iCount++)

                    // enter details
                    Console.Write("Please Enter your Name" + iCount + ": ");
            sName = Console.ReadLine();

            // write to file
            sw.WriteLine(sName);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("Please Enter the Name of your School: ");
            iSchoolName = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("Please Enter the name of your class: ");
            iClassName = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: This code won't compile.  Please reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: I can see sw is object or StreamWriter  and you also told that you declared  on top, so its confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sw` is only valid in the context of the `using`. You have no `{}` after your `using` which means the context is for the next statement ONLY;

```
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("NewUser.txt", true))

        //loop for each user
        for (iCount = 1; iCount <= iUserNumber; iCount++)

            // enter details
            Console.Write("Please Enter your Name" + iCount + ": ");
```

Any code beyond this is no longer in the context of the `using`. This means the `StreamWriter` has been disposed and is no longer available. To define more context, you have to put the code that is dependent on `sw` in `{}`

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("NewUser.txt", true))
{
    //loop for each user
    for (iCount = 1; iCount <= iUserNumber; iCount++)

        // enter details
        Console.Write("Please Enter your Name" + iCount + ": ");
    sName = Console.ReadLine();

    // write to file
    sw.WriteLine(sName);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Here, `sw` is still in context and available to use. I hope this makes sense.

**Edit**

Just a note; With regard to context, the `{}` is important. I see from your code that the `for` loop is missing it, too. This will not work as you expect either. If I entered `5`, the code will display "Please Enter your Name*n*" 5 times, and then wait for 1 name.

```
//loop for each user
for (iCount = 1; iCount <= iUserNumber; iCount++)
    // enter details
    Console.Write("Please Enter your Name" + iCount + ": ");
sName = Console.ReadLine();

// write to file
sw.WriteLine(sName);
Console.WriteLine();
```

`sname` is not in context of the loop. The loop will complete before that line is executed. You need `{}`

```
//loop for each user
for (iCount = 1; iCount <= iUserNumber; iCount++)
{
    // enter details
    Console.Write("Please Enter your Name" + iCount + ": ");
    sName = Console.ReadLine();

    // write to file
    sw.WriteLine(sName);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have missed the curly braces. Your code should look like

```
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("NewUser.txt", true))
{
                //loop for each user
                for (iCount = 1; iCount <= iUserNumber; iCount++)

                    // enter details
                    Console.Write("Please Enter your Name" + iCount + ": ");
            sName = Console.ReadLine();

            // write to file
            sw.WriteLine(sName);
    }
```